# Where I can find the Java Control Panel in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

It is very easy to locate it in Windows, but I can not find where I can access the Java's Control Panel in Ubuntu 14.

[Security level settings in the Java Control Panel](http://java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml#control%20panel)

I need to add one site exception, because the new version (Java 7) blocks pages that do not have certificates and are classified as entrusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed java to a particular location

```
cd /PATH/TO/YOUR/INSTALLATION/DIR 
./ControlPanel
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching in incorrect path, so i run the comand "readlink -f $(which java)" and found the path.

Comment: cheers Renato....

Answer (score 1):

on Ubuntu/mate:

```
systeme -> preferences -> IcedTea web control panel
```